# Is there a way to give the drawing red polygon a higher alpha channel

Tags: qgis, polygon, map-drawing

Is it possible to set the alpha channel a bit higher when drawing? I don't mean the alphachannel of a already finished polygon, that's possible for sure!

I mean the red area. It's really stressful because I need to see hwat is beyond that polygon and in many cases my painting is harmed.

So is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alpha and color! Enjoy digitizing :-)

[image]

[image]

[image]